# jquery mobile custom icon display not rendering properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Am trying to create a custom icon for a button in jQuery mobile. The size of the icon is `256px`

[image]

(Icon shown so you can see what i expect to see) When i view the page in my browser, this is how it is rendered:

[image]

My expectation is that the full icon is displayed.Am wondering why it is like this.Here is the html code for that page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile- 

1.2.0.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <style type="text/css">

.ui-icon-wallet {
    background-image: url("images/wallet16.png");
    background-size: 18px 18px;

}
 </style>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    <a href="templates/profile.html" data-role="button"  data-iconpos="right" data-

    icon="wallet" >View Balance</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>My Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried increasing and reducing the background size to no avail.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't see this class in your html code, is it there?

Comment: The `DOCTYPE` declaration should be in all caps, btw: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HVMHm/

Comment: @Dharman I don't get, do you mean `class="wallet"`?

Comment: no, I found it already. Your JS does the class insertion automatically for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This css shim should help:

```
.ui-icon-wallet {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/T06je.png");
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    background-color: inherit;
    width: 32px;
    height:32px;
    margin-top:-16px !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HVMHm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add 'background-color:transparent;' to only display the background-image.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dharman said, if you want a background image on the `.ui-icon-wallet` class, you'd have to apply that class to the element. Unless you've got a script somewhere that inspects items with `data-icon` attributes and autofills them, you need to change your `a` declaration to:

```
<a href="templates/profile.html" data-role="button"  data-iconpos="right" class="ui-icon-wallet" >View Balance</a>
```

And then adjust your CSS accordingly; as it's written, it will repeat a tiny icon over and over. For example:

```
.ui-icon-wallet {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/T06je.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 48px 48px;
    background-position: 98% 50%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/md9Q8/)

Comment: JQUERY-UI does the autofill for him.